# Register program on windows registry so that it appears on "Uninstall a program" on Control Panel

Tags: windows, installation, registry

Let's say I have a simple program: `SomeProgram.exe` and `Uninstaller.exe` those programs are in `C:\ProgramFiles\MyProgram`  along with several dll's and resources.

Anyways I have a simple installer that installs several prerequisites to that path. **Now my question is** how can I register `SomeProgram.exe` on window registry so that I can have it appear in add or remove programs in control panel. I will like to execute `Uninstaller.exe` when the user clicks on remove my program. Also I will like to create a folder on windows startup menu so that the user can start the program from there in case he does not want to have a shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368032(v=vs.85).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Helpful links thanks! I don't use window's installer because it was very complicated to include in there the prerequisites that I need therefore I decided to create my own installer which is an AutoIt program.

Comment: Erm, wait, how are you going to install AutoIt?

Comment: No, don't write an installer in AutoIt? Use a real tool designed for the job. If Windows Installer is too hard for you use something like InnoSetup.

Comment: AutoIt does not need to be installed. The reason why I will like to make this work is because my installer right now is basically an autoIt  program that uses IE broswer embedded in a form so the installer looks very professional. I can customize it a lot. I am just missing to add the program to to the registry somehow so that it appears on control panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is to create the registry entries as documented in the second link from "sergmat". This will make the program to appear in the list from Control Panel.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx